# Error: Failed to serialize user into session

Tags: mysql, node.js, serialization, passport.js, passport-local

I am using mysql with nodejs. I am getting "Error: failed to serialize user into session". When I console.log user in serializeuser function it prints "serialize [object Object]" and in "local-login" strategy it prints RowDataPacket as shown below.

```
RowDataPacket {
  Patient_id: 2,
  fname: 'xxx',
  mname: 'yyy',
  lname: 'zzz',
  Email: 'xxx@yyy.com',
  pass: '$2b$10$ycZI4SLTJEihxKDHpCXwcOhkmBiOKzmMqFyuEOgXa0KuXYupgaMeG',
  Contact: '090078601',
  Gender: 'Male',
  dateofbirth: 1111-01-13T19:31:48.000Z,
  Blood_group: null
}
```

```
// used to serialize the user for the session
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log(`serialize ${user}`)
    done(null, user.patient_id)
})

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    // connection.connect()
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM PATIENT WHERE PATIENT_ID = ? ",[id], function(err, rows){
        done(err, rows[0])
    })
    // connection.end()
})
```

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
},
function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form
    // connection.connect()
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM PATIENT WHERE EMAIL = ?",[email],function(err,rows){
            if (err)
                return done(err)
            if (!rows.length) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'No user found.')) // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash
            } 

            bcrypt.compare(password, rows[0].pass, function(err, result) {
                if(!result)
                {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'Oops! Wrong password.'))
                }
                // console.log(rows[0])
            });
            return done(null, rows[0])
        })
    // connection.end()
    }
))
```

my post login look like this

```
router.post('/patient/login',  ensureGuest, passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect : '/home', // redirect to the secure profile section
        failureRedirect : 'login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
    })
);
```

don't suggest to use session:false while authenticating in post method

Answer (score 0):

The type of object being returned by the sql query was causing the problem, serialize and deserialize accepts json object so I just added stringifyObjects option in my connection configs so that sql query returns json objects and not the default type of object which it usually returns.

```
module.exports = {
    'connection': {
        'host': 'localhost',
        'user': 'root',
        'password': 'fast',
        'database': 'hms',
        'stringifyObjects': 'Stringify' 
    }
};
```